# Issues in Sping integration mail idle receiver

Tags: email, spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

I'm using spring integration mail in order to receive mail messages from several configurable accounts.

I'm using IMAP server and idle configuration

I wrote the following code:

```
@Autowired
private IntegrationFlowContext flowContext;
IntegrationFlow flow = null;
String userFlag = confMailIn.getHost() + "_idle_adapter";
ImapIdleChannelAdapterSpec imapIdleChannelAdapterSpec = Mail.imapIdleAdapter(connectionUrl.toString())
        .javaMailProperties(javaMailProperties)
        .shouldDeleteMessages(deleteMessages)
        .shouldMarkMessagesAsRead(markMessagesRead)
        .autoStartup(true)
        .autoCloseFolder(false)
        .userFlag(userFlag)
        .id(userFlag)
        //.searchTermStrategy(this::notSeenTerm)
        .selector(selectFunction);

if (confMailIn.isRichiedeAutenticazione()) {
    imapIdleChannelAdapterSpec = imapIdleChannelAdapterSpec.javaMailAuthenticator(new CasellaPostaleAuthenticator(cpd.getIndirizzoMail(), cpd.getUsername(), cpd.getPassword()));
}
flow = IntegrationFlows
        .from(imapIdleChannelAdapterSpec)
        .handle(message ->{
            //Prendo il closable del messaggio e valorizzo i l'elenco di closeale da chiudere
            Closeable closeable = StaticMessageHeaderAccessor.getCloseableResource(message);
            if( !closeables.containsKey(cpd.getIndirizzoMail()) ) {
                closeables.put(cpd.getIndirizzoMail(), closeable);
            }
            publishMailEvent(message);
        })
        .get();
flowContext.registration(flow).id(flowId).register();
```

I set to false the auto close folder because if it's true I can't handle the mail message because I receive a `FolderClosedException`. So I collect all the `Closeable` objects and I close them when Spring context is closed (in the best scenario.... never :) )

So far so good... I register the flow and it starts working. But I noticed that after some time it stops in receiving mail messages. I need to restart my service and once again it works for some time.

When it works I see these logs:

```
2020-04-20 16:32:57,427 25199841 [scheduling-1] DEBUG o.s.i.mail.ImapIdleChannelAdapter - waiting for mail 
2020-04-20 16:32:57,460 25199874 [scheduling-1] INFO  o.s.i.mail.ImapMailReceiver - attempting to receive mail from folder [INBOX] 
2020-04-20 16:32:57,460 25199874 [scheduling-1] DEBUG o.s.i.mail.ImapMailReceiver - This email server does not support RECENT flag, but it does support USER flags which will be used to prevent duplicates during email fetch. This receiver instance uses flag: imapmail.libero.it_idle_adapter 
2020-04-20 16:32:57,476 25199890 [scheduling-1] DEBUG o.s.i.mail.ImapMailReceiver - found 0 new messages 
2020-04-20 16:32:57,476 25199890 [scheduling-1] DEBUG o.s.i.mail.ImapMailReceiver - Received 0 messages 
2020-04-20 16:32:57,476 25199890 [scheduling-1] DEBUG o.s.i.mail.ImapIdleChannelAdapter - received 0 mail messages 
2020-04-20 16:32:57,476 25199890 [scheduling-1] DEBUG o.s.i.mail.ImapIdleChannelAdapter - Task completed successfully. Re-scheduling it again right away.
```

But after some time it stops in writing. I have the sensation that it's related to the Flag options but I can't figure out how to solve the issue.

Any tip is more than welcome

Thank you

Angelo

Comment: Doesn't it continue printing those logs after "Re-scheduling it again right away." when you use `autoCloseFolder(true)` ?

Comment: If I use `autoCloseFolder(true)` and I only log a simple print (e.g. mail message received) all works pretty good..

Comment: Ok. So, sounds like we need to close a folder when no new messages to let it to idle in between. Please, raise a GH issue and we’ll think!

Comment: OK. How can I raise the GH issue? In the meantime if I set `autoCloseFolder(true)` May I use the DefaultMailHeaderMapper in order to hanlde the mime message and its attachment?

Answer (score 0):

Please, raise a GH issue over here https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/issues.

As a workaround you might need to follow an approach suggested over here in docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.3.0.M4/reference/html/mail.html#mail-tx-sync. See `Mover`. I mean you need to consider to *reopen* the folder to be able to process attachments from the message.

Comment: Hi Artem; I raised the GH issue (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/issues/3257) and I'll give a look to the workaround. Thank you